# Dropdown placeholder divider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to have a divider in my `select` dropdown, for example:

```
<select name="season" class="season">
    <option value="">Select season</option>
    {% for season in search_item.get_seasons %}
        <option value="{{ season }}">{{ season }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option>---------------------------</option>
    <option value="-1">I need to create a new season for this item</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to create a value with the width of the longest option? For example I would like the `--------` divider to have the (approximate) width of the longest value in there. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, assuming you don't mind a bit of 'spacing' in your line.

Considering you already have `search_item.get_seasons`, you can run [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) on each `season` to find which one is the longest, by looping through each and overwriting a variable if the current item has a longer `.length`. From here you can simply set the [`.innerHTML`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the relevant `<select>` to be equal to a `-` multiplied by that variable (which now contains the `.length` of the longest item). I've used [`.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to cover that.

Note that you'll want to make use of a monospaced font (such as Courier) for optimal results.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const items = [
  "A season",
  "A really, really long season",
  "Short season"
];

let longest = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].length > longest) {
    longest = items[i].length;
  }
}

const element = document.querySelector('.line');
element.innerHTML = "-".repeat(longest);
```

```css
select {
  font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<select name="season" class="season">
  <option value="">Select season</option>
  <option value="">A season</option>
  <option value="">A really, really long season</option>
  <option value="">Short season</option>
  <option class="line"></option>
  <option value="-1">I need to create a new season for this item</option>
</select>
```